# Azure machine learning studio designer UI unresponsive

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to use AMLS to do some stuff. However, the designer component wont let me type in any text fields in it. For example, export data component by azureml wont let me type in anything for parameters like export data table name, columns to export, or column names in export data table. These fields are mandatory fields so I must fill it out to save it. I have tried recreating workspace, recreate component, recreate pipeline, different browsers, cleaning out cache, and different computer. When I click the field to type in the parameter, it won't take in anything and nothing I type will be put in. Copy paste also do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-Requisites for this operation are as follows:

1. Create a datastore and get the output folder path
2. Create a computer instance or cluster
3. Open designer

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The datastore looks like below:

[image]

Comment: I am  using SQL Database datastore.  I cannot type in any of the fields in it.